# onChage multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange

I have got Django Rest Framework backend and I am trying to post data there via React. Fetching the data is working fine. If I tried to post data with only one input it also worked fine. But when I try add more inputs, it does not work and I dont know how to handle multiple inputs..

React Code:

```
class Activity2project extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {
           virtualProjectList:[],
           activeItem:{
                id:null,
                project_name:'',
                project_name_RnD:'',
            },
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.fetchVirtualProjects = this.fetchVirtualProjects.bind(this)
        }

         handleChange(e){
             var name = e.target.name
             var value = e.target.value

             this.setState({
                activeItem:{
                    ...this.state.activeItem,
                    project_name:e.target.value,
                    project_name_RnD:e.target.value,
                      }
                })
          }
          
          render(){
          <div>
             <input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='virtual_project' name='virtual_project_name' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name} placeholder='Project Name' ></input>
             <input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='virtual_project_RnD' name='virtual_project_name_RnD' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name_RnD} placeholder='Project Name RnD' ></input>
             <input id='submit' type='submit' name='Add'></input>
          </div>
          }
```

With this it writes the same value into inputs and I dont now how to distinguish these two inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give your input fields ids that matches the attributes of your state:

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='project_name' name='virtual_project_name' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name} placeholder='Project Name' ></input>
<input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='project_name_RnD' name='virtual_project_name_RnD' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name_RnD} placeholder='Project Name RnD' ></input>
```

and then in `changeHandler`:

```
let id = event.target.id;
// then using computed property name 
activeItem: {
    ...this.state.activeItem,
    [id]: event.target.value
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but if I try to write into inputs they stay empty. In console log it shows it took only first character and then it reloads. See here: https://imgur.com/pkG6c7C

Comment: are you aware of the fact that the code you posted in your question is missing some parentheses? after putting these missing parentheses the code started to work.
i will post an image from codesandbox.io.

Comment: I noticed the same - the code is a touch messy. There's missing parentheses, and formatting errors, but it didn't fix the problem as the handleChange targets both inputs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` brackets to bind the value of the object key to the `name` of the input.

For example:

```
handleChange(e) {
  var name = e.target.name;
  var value = e.target.value;

  this.setState({
    activeItem: {
      ...this.state.activeItem,
      [name]: e.target.value
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for you reply. I tried this, but now in the first input it wont take any value and the only char is copied to the second input.

Comment: I tried this, but if I try to write into inputs they stay empty. In console log it shows it took only first character and then it reloads. See here: imgur.com/pkG6c7C

Comment: @pipikej are you sure you removed the other parts of your original `setState`? This should work if you copied it exactly as it is here. Although I would also recommend spreading the rest of state too (`...this.state, activeItem: ...etc`) otherwise you'll end up losing other values.

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes, I removed the other parts.And it does not work. The inputs are still empty. Screen: https://imgur.com/I9yMMrb

Comment: Please include a reproducible example. Without one this will be much harder to help with.

Comment: @BrianThompson I reproduced it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-darwin-9w3xx   Thank you for your time

Comment: @pipikej As some of the answers have pointed out, the `name` of your inputs must match the name of the state key that you are using to dynamically update. You're dynamically updating `virtual_project_name`, but setting the input value to `project_name`. The must match.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is attempting to alter both inputs at the same time. That's the reason why you can see both inputs adding the same text, as your app can't differentiate between the targets.

The following code will allow your app to see the target, check its name, and then handleChange will set the state assuming the name matches one of the available options.

As a result, the name of the inputs should reflect the state name, like so:

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='virtual_project' name='project_name' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name} placeholder='Project Name' ></input>
           <input onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' id='virtual_project_RnD' name='project_name_RnD' value={this.state.activeItem.project_name_RnD} placeholder='Project Name RnD' ></input>
```

And then changing handleChange to the following should work:

```
handleChange = (e) => {

           this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        }
```

Hope that works.